# Kotlin sealed interface with generic type doesn't infer constraints for it's subtypes

Tags: kotlin, generics

Example:

```kotlin
sealed interface Foo<out T> {
    val value: T
}

data class Bar<out K: List<Int>>(override val value: K): Foo<K>
    
fun <T> processFoo(foo: Foo<T>) {
    
    when (foo) {
        is Bar -> foo.value.forEach(::println)
    }
}
```

Fails with:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
> because of receiver type mismatch:
>
> - `public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit` defined in `kotlin.collections`
> - `public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit` defined in `kotlin.collections`

Why this fails? I expect that if `foo` is of type `Bar` then we know that `T` is a subtype of `List<Int>`. So we should be able to call `forEach` on it. Am I wrong?

Comment: It doens't really answer your question for why it fails. But I believe you can simply do `data class Bar(override val value: List<Int>): Foo<List<Int>>` to make it work. I'm not sure why you would even use `K` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect that if foo is of type Bar then we know that T is a subtype of List. So we should be able to call forEach on it.

Yes, that is true. But `T` could also implement `Map<K, V>` *at the same time* as it implements `List<Int>` (I don't know of such a type, but it theoretically could exist), in which case you would also be able to call this extension function:

```
inline fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.forEach(
    action: (Entry<K, V>) -> Unit)
```

See all the different `forEach`es [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html).

To specifically call the `forEach` defined for `Iterable`, just do a cast:

```
// could also cast to List<Int> here - that's a completely safe unchecked cast
(foo.value as List<*>).forEach(::println)
```

An alternative is to use `is Bar<*>`, but a (very) slight drawback of this is that, as `<*>` projects the type of `foo.value` to be `List<Int>`, you lose the `T`. You won't be able to use `foo.value` in places where a `T` is expected.

A contrived example would be:

```
fun <T> processFoo(foo: Foo<T>): T {
    return when (foo) {
        // you can't return foo.value when you are expected to return T
        is Bar<*> -> foo.value.also { 
            it.forEach(::println) 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is simply caused by a typo in your code.

If you replace `is Bar` with `is Bar<*>`, the compiler is able to infer that `T` is a `List<Int>` in that context and the code compiles.

Comment: @f.smith Just to add more detail here, what the `<*>` does is that it projects the type variable `T` to its bound, `List<Int>`. This changes the type of `value` from `T` to `List<Int>`. I totally thought `is Bar` and `is Bar<*>` mean completely different things (i.e. the comparison behaviour would be different), but apparently not :)

Comment: So what does `is Bar` actually *do* without the type argument? Because I was trying to figure that out locally, and it seems to not do any kind of smart cast at all. Is it some sort of legacy raw types thing?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo There is actually a (small) difference regarding what happens after. If you use `is Bar`, the type of `foo.value` is `T`, so e.g. if `processFoo` is declared to return `T`, you can `return foo.value` after the `is Bar` check. You *cannot* `return foo.value` if it were a `is Bar<*>` check, because its type is `List<Int>`.

Comment: @f.smith You might want to know this too.